# Select random item from table with ratio

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to create an mysql table with some data in it which are special items. For example we have item1(chanse: 1), item2(chanse: 1), item(chance: 20%) and 
item3 (chance: 20) etc.. etc...
- Chances are in %

So I created a table with the following information:

```
CREATE TABLE `special_items` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_type` enum('SPECIAL','SILVER','BRONZE','GOLD') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'BRONZE',
  `item_ratio` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `item` (`item_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of special_items
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `special_items` VALUES ('1', '200', 'special_name1', 'BRONZE', '80');
INSERT INTO `special_items` VALUES ('2', '204', 'special_name2', 'BRONZE', '4');
INSERT INTO `special_items` VALUES ('3', '875', 'special_name3', 'BRONZE', '80');
INSERT INTO `special_items` VALUES ('4', '900', 'special_name4', 'BRONZE', '60');
INSERT INTO `special_items` VALUES ('5', '901', 'special_name5', 'SILVER', '90');
INSERT INTO `special_items` VALUES ('6', '968', 'special_name6', 'BRONZE', '65');
INSERT INTO `special_items` VALUES ('7', '777', 'special_name7', 'BRONZE', '30');
```

What we want to do now is select from 800 rows 5 random items by there ratio. So it needs to have the following requirements:

- Always random rows.
- Select rows by there ratio (chance in the table is percentage for example)

I also found this query which almost fits the solution but its don't know how I would do this for the random ratio (percentage)

```
SELECT item_name
  FROM special_items AS r1 JOIN
       (SELECT CEIL(RAND() *
                     (SELECT MAX(id)
                        FROM special_items)) AS id)
        AS r2
 WHERE r1.id >= r2.id
 ORDER BY r1.id ASC
 LIMIT 5
```

If this can be done through PHP it would be awesome.

I'm open to any and all suggestions. I'll also be trying to figure this out on my own in the meantime, but I'm still stuck.

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: What do the chances mean?  They don't add up to 1, for instance.  And how many rows do you have in the table and how many are being selected?  Is this a random subset or superset?

Comment: Select 5 items randomly is easy, but the ratio restriction isnt clear.

Comment: there will be 800 items in the database which all have a percentage chance ratio. When selecting there will be always 5 rows selected and based on the chanse which is in percentage.

Comment: what is that `chance ratio`? how the `chance` affec the selecting? Please give us one example.

Comment: Example of how it needs to be working: Item 1 - Chance for getting this row 1% Item 2 - Chance for getting this row 3% Item 3 - Chance for getting this row 20% Item 4 - Chance for getting this row 25% Item 5 - Chance for getting this row 90% Item 6 - Chance for getting this row 25% Restriction is that you always get 5 rows based on random select and the chance of getting the row.

Comment: so the column `item_ratio` is the `chance` of being selected?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Explain: Simple algorithm that allows to select random rows taking into consideration so called weight values, so some of the rows will be selected more often than other according to this weight values.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess that by "chanse" [sic], you mean that each row has a weight, and you want this weight to contribute to the chance of a row being selected.

One method is to generate a random number for each row, multiply by the weight, and then return 5 rows with the highest generated number.  It is unclear what you mean by the chance, so this might do what you want:

```
select si.*
from (select si.*, rand() * item_ratio as weight
      from special_items si
     ) si
order by weight desc
limit 5;
```

Note:  The subquery is needed so the `weight` is only calculated once per line.  I think this does the same thing:

```
select si.*, rand() * item_ratio as weight
from special_items si
order by weight desc
limit 5;
```

But MySQL can be peculiar.

Comment: Example of how it needs to be working:  
    
Item 1 - Chance for getting this row 1%  
Item 2 - Chance for getting this row 3%    
Item 3 - Chance for getting this row 20%    
Item 4 - Chance for getting this row 25%    
Item 5 - Chance for getting this row 90%    
Item 6 - Chance for getting this row 25%    
       
Restriction is that you always get 5 rows based on random select and the   chance of getting the row. @Gordon Linoff

Comment: I used the function RAND() since i didnt know what you meen by the function random? Can you explain that?

Comment: Explain: Simple algorithm that allows to select random rows taking into consideration so called weight values, so some of the rows will be selected more often than other according to this weight values.